# How to refactor ViewSet that retrieves records created by authenticated user

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need these methods to retrieve/update/delete records created by authenticated user only. I'm clearly violating one of the key principles of web/software development. How can i refactor this viewset?

```
class AddressViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Address.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AddressSerializer
    authentication_classes = (JWTAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = Address.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return super(AddressViewSet, self).list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = Address.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return super(AddressViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = Address.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return super(AddressViewSet, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = Address.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return super(AddressViewSet, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = Address.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return super(AddressViewSet, self).destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Could you provide the models that go with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add get_queryset method and remove filtering by user in other methods:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = Address.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    return queryset
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly specify request as an argument, but thanks, that what i was looking for!